# Ubuntu 20.04 dual monitor not working with Intel HD graphics in Thinkpad X270

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, thinkpad

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad X270.

I use a docking station for work with two monitors connected, one via HDMI, one via DVI.

Up until Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade, everything worked fine.

However, now Ubuntu isn't able to detect the second monitor.

I do not seem to be able to control the graphics driver.  Having had a hunt around, I've read forums where the driver is described as being in the kernel - not sure whether that's true or not.

I really don't want to have to downgrade Ubuntu - I really like the sleakness of 20.04, and would like to keep it.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone having similar problem - the issue is with the fact the DVI port on my docking station stopped working with Ubuntu 20.  I switched second  monitor to HDMI and its working fine now.